# Can't get the output for VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub getDataFromOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Inbox")

    i = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items

        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value And Date <= 19 - feb - 2022 Then

            Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
            Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit

            Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName

            Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

            Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
            Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
            Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next OutlookMail

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I'm trying to learn VBA. So, I saw a youtube video and tried to run the code.

There is no error in the code. But I can't see the output in my excel sheet.

Comment: [Have you used VBA's debugger?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/trace-code-execution) If not, why not?

Comment: "There is no error in the code" ?? Add `Option Explicit` at top and you will see the error **variable not defined** on this line `Date <= 19 - feb - 2022`. What is that line meant to be doing ? , You haven't explained what output you want.